# Create Model Through Text Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I watched [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/57-create-model-through-text-field) on "Create Model Through Text Field" because I want a user to have the option of either selecting an existing project or creating a new one in a form. I followed along, but it's still not working for me. I have my code setup exactly as the video suggests:

Form:

```
<%= f.label :project_id %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :project_id, Project.order(:name), :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a project" %>
or create one:
<%= f.text_field :new_project_name %>
```

Model that form is for:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    attr_accessor :new_project_name
    before_save :create_project_from_name

    def create_project_from_name
        create_project(:name => new_project_name) unless new_project_name.blank?
    end
end
```

Project Model

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
end
```

Why is this not working for me?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you show your `Project` model?

Comment: I added the Project model. I'm not seeing an error.

Comment: If you're not seeing an error, then what do you mean when you say it isn't working?

Comment: The form goes through but no new project is created when I console the database.

Comment: No new `Project` is added or you don't see the association?

Comment: When I list all the products in the database in the console (Project.all) none show. So none were created via the form.

Answer (score 0):

For `Item`, you are specifying:

`belongs_to :factory_project`

and are using `create_project`.

Use `belongs_to :project`.

Comment: Whoops that was a typo that's not in my code. Still doesn't work without it.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. It needed to be in my permitted parameters.